# media server with sip functionality

Tags: media, sip, vxml

I tried using **Voxpilot media server** for sip request handling using vxml code , but lately voxpilot is *not working well* and the already running applications are not displaying expected behaviour.

I tried using **Mobicents media server** mms 3.0 , mss2.0 , mss1.5  but the approach *doesnt seem to be working* since my softphone reads no sample multimedia application as IVR or muticonf as given in user guide doc .

I tried exploring a little of **SEMS ( sip express media server )** but then the website reads "This website/URL has been blocked until further notice either pursuant to Court orders or on the Directions issued by the Department of Telecommunications" hence *no help* ..

- Can some one suggest me a workaround or a media server , open-source
  that can handle sip requests using vxml script ?

Answer (score 2):

There are some open source VoiceXML interpreters/browsers and some open source SIP media servers, but I am not aware of a good open source solution that supports both.  [OpenVXI](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/openvxi/) is a popular VoiceXML interpreter that many commercial IVR systems are based on.  [VoiceGlue](http://www.voiceglue.org/) is an open source implementation that combines OpenVXI with Asterisk under the GPL license.  You could try integrating OpenVXI with an open source SIP media server. You can get a list of [open source SIP solutions here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software). Integrating the two is not a small task. Nor is learning and supporting some of these open source solutions.

If you are not tied to open source I would look at [Voxeo Prophecy](http://voxeo.com/prophecy/). This is an excellent VoiceXML platform that uses SIP as main telephony interface. It is a software only solution that you can get two ports for development for free and the per port cost is very economical. Probably less than the time and effort to get an open source solution running.  It is extremely easy to install and get running and the support is excellent and free. Voxeo also offers this platform in the cloud as a service.